# Azure AD B2C want to differentiate between admin and users created by admin

Tags: azure

I am working on a webapplication and I am using Azure AD B2C tenant to manage my user and provide authentication system.I want that whenever user signup through my Azure AD B2C tenant he become root(admin) in my app.Being admin he can create user(using Microsoft graph) in my app but those users should not be considered as admin.My question is how can I differentiate between admin and user created by that admin in my app??????

Answer (score 0):

> I want that whenever user signup through my Azure AD B2C tenant he
> become root(admin) in my app.

You cannot enable users to have the admin role when registering. You must complete the user registration before granting him the admin role.

[image]

> My question is how can I differentiate between admin and user created
> by that admin in my app??????

In the portal, you can only distinguish between administrator users, Member users and guest users. It cannot distinguish which administrator created the user.